# A way to refresh Firefox in the background?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I'm happily typing HTML in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) on my Windows machine with 2 monitors, one has Notepad++ and the other has Firefox.

After I finished typing the HTML I would like to see the updated result in Firefox, so I click the Firefox window to highlight it (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to it when I only have a few windows open), and then press F5, and I see my updated page.

What I want is to have some keyboard shortcut to refresh Firefox while I'm still working in Notepad++, so that I don't have to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> all the time.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using this:
http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/

and this:
http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could just right-click on the page and choose Reload Every..., then choose how often you want to reload the page.

**Edit:** `Reload Every` is available as part of the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/) addon, or the [Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/) addon.

Comment: Probably helps if they have that extension installed...  @YuriKolovsky: Here's the URL if you want to explore this solution (I use it myself for the same thing you are): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/

Comment: @Mistiry - I don't have that addon...Okay, just checked and it must have come as part of Tab Mix Plus (which I load on every Firefox install). Thanks for the correction - I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: reloading the page every now and then, although useful for just html/css, but would be a big problem when writing server side code... (oh and thx for the link Mistiry)

Comment: Would it be possible to create some windows key combination or notepad++ function or something that runs a refresh on all firefox windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a hotkey, you can do it with scripting. [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) has options for this sort of purpose. You will need the [Firefox Library](http://thorsten-willert.de/Themen/FFau3/FF.au3/FF.au3) and the [MozRepl plugin](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/).

Here is the script that will do it for you:

```
HotKeySet("!M",'_FFRefresh') ;sets hotkey to Alt+Shift+m to trigger function

While 1 ;loop to keep alive

WEnd

Func _FFRefresh()
    _FFConnect() ;connect to firefox
    _FFAction("reload") ;refresh window
    _FFDisConnect() ;disconnect from firefox
EndFunc
```

Comment: this is new to me, I will try it out and report back tomorrow.

Comment: This will only work on the last active tab at the moment, but I'll see if I can figure out how to refresh everything.

Comment: so I download & install autoIt v3, then I install mozRepl plugin, what then what? could you make a small mini-guide for the less experienced?

Comment: So the MozRepl plugin provides the COM interface that the firefox library needs. You can set it to autostart and then start it in the Firefox Tools Menu under MozRepl. The firefox library gets saved in the Include folder of your AutoIt installation. You will have a basic version of Scite that came with AutoIt that you can edit scripts in. You can also compile them there using Ctrl+F7. You would just need to copy and paste the script above into Scite and save it. You can run the script from Scite, you can right click it in explorer and run it, or you can compile it and run it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://code-section.com/refreshbrowser - it refreshes the browser when you save the document in Notepad++